# Recovering Google Drive File Stream files lost due to system failure during upload

Tags: google-drive-api, recover

I have a Windows system which failed while uploading some Google Drive File Stream files.  How do I get those files back/continue the upload?

(This was due to system file corruption - all user data is still intact)

Answer (score 0):

You will need all the data from `%localappdata%\Google`, as well as the location you set as the "Local cached files directory" in Google Drive File Stream, (GDFS) if it's different from the default.  (It defaults to `%localappdata%\Google\DriveFS`)

1. Copy the `%localappdata%\Google` from the dead system to `%localappdata%` on the donor system
2. Change the permissions on `%localappdata%\Google` on the donor system so the current user has access
3. Start GDFS
4. Despite the `%localappdata%\Google` folder containing a login token, GDFS won't be able to login as it's missing something from the Windows Credential Store; Login to GDFS using the account the original system was logged in as
5. GDFS is now accessible and will resume syncing any files that were in progress on the original machine.